# How to split an image using MATLAB Mat2Cell

Tags: matlab

I have an image with 4476x9058 pixels. I'm trying to use mat2cell to split it into subimages with 100x300 pixels each. However, I'm getting the error:

**Input arguments, D1 through D2, must sum to
each dimension of the input matrix size,
[4476  9058].**

The code is shown below:

```
image =rand(4476,9058);
blockSizeRow = 100;            
blockSizeCol = 300;

[nrows, ncols] = size(image);
nBlocksRow = floor(nrows / blockSizeRow);
nBlocksCol = floor(ncols / blockSizeCol);
rowDist = [blockSizeRow * ones(1, nBlocksRow), mod(nrows, nBlocksRow)];
colDist = [blockSizeCol * ones(1, nBlocksCol), mod(ncols, nBlocksCol)];
blockImages = mat2cell(image, rowDist, colDist,1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `mod(nrows, nBlocksRow)` to `mod(nrows, blockSizeRow)`, and `mod(ncols, nBlocksCol)` to `mod(ncols, blockSizeCol)`